# Process.Start starts the process two times instead of one

Tags: c#, process.start

I got two executables (Program1.exe and Program2.exe) which each open the other one when closed:

Here some code from Program1.exe:

```
private void Main_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
   Application.Exit();
   Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Program2.exe");
}
```

However, when I do this, it opens *two* windows instead of one. Is there any way to let it open one window only?

Comment: @Closevoter did you tried first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Application.Exit` will call `FormClosing` event one more time. So `Process.Start` is called twice and thus it opens twice.

Move the following code in `FormClosed` event

```
private void Main_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\Program2.exe");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing `Application.Exit();`.

It calls `Main_FormClosing`